# Checking if all vertices are connect in a loop

Tags: python, pygame, polygon

I am writing a project where you can draw a polygon with vertices and lines connecting them and then run them into a physics engine like pymunk.

I want to make sure that all the vertices are connected in a loop like this
[image]

And if it isn't connected fully like so

[image]
Each vertex is a Vertex object which is below

```
class Vertex():
    def __init__(self, id, position, pointsTo = [], rectSize = [10, 10]):
        self.id = int(id)
        self.position = tuple(position)
        self.rect = tuple((position[0], position[1], rectSize[0], rectSize[1]))
        self.pointsTo = list(pointsTo)

    def setPosition(self, position):
        self.position = tuple((position[0] - (self.rect[2] / 2), position[1] - (self.rect[3] / 2)))
        self.rect = tuple((self.position[0], self.position[1], self.rect[2], self.rect[3]))

    def getRect(self):
        return self.rect
```

Where pointsTo is a list of the vertices that are connected to that vertex
.How would I find if a list of vertices are connected together in a loop

Comment: Is `pointsTo` a list of Vertex instances?

Comment: @Artyer Yes, sorry for the slow reply.

Comment: Just to check that all the adjacency lists have exactly two elements, in the graph g, which is a list of vertex objects: all(map(lambda v: 2==len(v.pointsTo), g))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we think of it as a graph, we have the vertex, and pointsTo is an adjacency list of edges. I am also assuming an undirected graph, based on the illustration in the question, so if A->B then B->A. We can think of a polygon as an N-cycle. I am ignoring the possibility of edges crossing on the screen with no actual vertex in the graph.

Suppose it is an N-cycle. Then every vertex has exactly two edges, and all vertices are connected. Both of those are easy to test for.

(Note: if every vertex has exactly two edges, then you have linked up. The connected test is just to see if there are multiple polygons, or just one, and to make the proof easier. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Bridges_of_K%C3%B6nigsberg for a similar concept. As that famous problem shows, you could test for even, if you allow multiple polygons but just want to test for extra lines not linked up into a polygon.)

Now, suppose a graph passes the above test -- hypothetically, start at any point and start visiting the pointsTo vertices following the graph, never using a previously visited edge/vertex. Every time you visit a new vertex, it is the first time you have been there, therefore you cannot have used the other pointsTo at that vertex, so you can continue until you run out of vertices. At that time, you have two unused pointsTo -- one into the start vertex, and one out of the end vertex. Either they pointsTo a vertex that doesn't exist, or they pointsTo each other, meaning it is an N-cycle.

Thus the above test is proven.

I said it is easy to test for things, so I should do so: To test that the graph is connected, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)

add a visited flag (initialized to false) to all vertices. Pick any vertex, and start visiting neighbors. When you run out, see if any vertex has not been visited.

or make a set of vertex.id's, add them when visited. At the end, check len(that set) is the number of vertices in the graph

Comment: How about if The graph is connected A-B-C-D-E-B and you start from A? Seems like you'd still visit each node once but you'd have a "tail" from your polygon leading from B to A. You also need to verify that the last node you visit is the same as the first.

Comment: That counterexample doesn't pass the test, so would be considered not a polygon. B is connected to three other vertices A, C, E. Also A is connected only to B.

Comment: Apologies, I must've skimmed over that sentence.

Comment: @KennyOstrom So would I be able to apply DFS to the graph similarly to BFS? I'm only asking because I have already got experience using DFS.

Comment: Either will work, and in fact on the usual graph (a polygon), they are identical, since you literally never have a choice where to go next, because there is always just one option (until you are done, obviously).

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at the definition of a [Strongly Connected Component](https://alg12.wikischolars.columbia.edu/file/view/SCC.pdf/317585592/SCC.pdf) and then test if your graph as represented by your `Vertex` and `Edges` i.e `Vertex.pointsTo` forms a strongly Connected Component comprising of all the Vertices in your list.

Comment: This only works if the links are one way, and we don't see how the graph was set up. The illustration suggests undirected, but the code suggests it is directed, with no return link being set up.

Comment: An undirected graph is just a directed graph with two directed edges between A->B and B->A representing the undirected edge A-B where A and B are vertices.

Comment: Yes, and that's what I assumed, but in that case a non-polygon is a SCC comprising all the vertices, meaning that checking for SCC doesn't work for detecting a polygon.  If the links are one way, then checking the SCC works because you can't get back to the start unless they link up in a cycle. We just have two different answers, one of which will work depending on how the graph is set up, and we don't know which.

Comment: Then you need to check if your graph has a cycle comprising of all the vertices. You can pre-process your list of vertexes to create a directed graph i.e if A points to B and B points to A, take out the first edge A->B so only B->A remains. And continue in-order for all vertices. Then just start with vertex the last vertex and keep going to the pointsTo till  your count of vertices traversed exceeds the total number of vertices you have. If you reach back to the same vertice you started at and have vertices traversed equal to total number of vertices, it is a polygon.